# Block Internet Access for specific machines via EdgeRouter with reject

Tags: networking, firewall

I have an EdgeRouter and I'm trying to block internet access to certain machines using "reject" instead of "drop". The goal is the machine that is blocked will quickly fail connections to the internet. As it is I have it blocked but it does not fail quickly. Connections must timeout which can take 1 to 4 minutes per app.

I currently have 3 network groups

```
    group {
        network-group LocalOnly {
            description "Local Lan Only"
            network 192.168.0.0/16
        }
        network-group TheInternet {
            description "Everything External"
            network 0.0.0.0/1
            network 128.0.0.0/2
            network 192.0.0.0/3
            network 224.0.0.0/4
        }
        network-group WindowsLaptops {
            description "Windows Laptops"
            network 192.168.1.54/31
        }
    }
```

And my firewall is set like this

```
    name BlockInternet {
        default-action accept
        description "Block Windows"
        rule 1 {
            action accept
            description "Allow Local"
            destination {
                group {
                    network-group LocalOnly
                }
            }
            log disable
            protocol all
            source {
                group {
                    network-group WindowsLaptops
                }
            }
        }
        rule 2 {
            action reject
            description "Block Internet"
            destination {
                group {
                    network-group TheInternet
                }
            }
            log disable
            protocol all
            source {
                group {
                    network-group WindowsLaptops
                }
            }
        }
    }
    name WAN_IN {
        default-action drop
        description "WAN to internal"
        rule 10 {
            action accept
            description "Allow established/related"
            state {
                established enable
                related enable
            }
        }
        rule 20 {
            action drop
            description "Drop invalid state"
            state {
                invalid enable
            }
        }
    }
    name WAN_LOCAL {
        default-action drop
        description "WAN to router"
        rule 10 {
            action accept
            description "Allow established/related"
            state {
                established enable
                related enable
            }
        }
        rule 20 {
            action drop
            description "Drop invalid state"
            state {
                invalid enable
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm pretty sure `WAN_IN` and `WAN_LOCAL` are defaults (though maybe I have a bad memory)

I added `BlockInternet` which seems straight forward. It seems to say if a network request comes in from `WindowsLaptops` and is going to `LocalOnly` then allow the requested. If the request is for `TheInternet` reject it.

But it's not acting like a "reject". Reject I'd expect to happen immediately. Instead it takes 1 to 4 minutes for an app (browser, other) to timeout.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are not theoretically wrong here, but your form could be clearer. For BlockInternet, I would set default-action to reject. Keep rule 1 exactly how it is, get rid of rule 2. Generally you never need to define "the internet". It should be caught by the default-action policy, if applicable.

Comment: Also, I assume you actually bound this rule to your LAN in?

Comment: It's bound to `SWITCH` in

Answer (score 1):

So instead of testing via apps I tested via `ping` and it was rejecting. `ping` returns "destination unreachable" with the config above vs "timeout" if I switch "reject" -> "drop"

But, other apps were still timing out. I switched from "reject" -> "reject tcp" which also meant I had to switch the protocol to "tcp".  After that the apps started timing out! Yay!

Now though, "ping" was not blocked. So I added a 3rd rule to with "reject" + "protocol all" and it seems to be working.

```
    name BlockInternet {
        default-action accept
        description "Block Windows"
        rule 1 {
            action accept
            description "Allow Local"
            destination {
                group {
                    network-group LocalOnly
                }
            }
            log disable
            protocol all
            source {
                group {
                    network-group WindowsLaptops
                }
            }
        }
        rule 2 {
            action reject-tcp
            description "Block Internet TCP"
            destination {
                group {
                    network-group TheInternet
                }
            }
            log disable
            protocol tcp
            source {
                group {
                    network-group WindowsLaptops
                }
            }
        }
        rule 3 {
            action reject
            description "Block Internet"
            destination {
                group {
                    network-group TheInternet
                }
            }
            log disable
            protocol all
            source {
                group {
                    network-group WindowsLaptops
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Apps now start quicker instead of really long timeouts.

I have no idea if this is correct or best but it seems to work